TypeInitializationException in OwnedInstanceRegistrationSource for MAUI Release Android
I have MAUI application which works fine in debug mode, but in release it throws such exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: TypeInitialization_Type, Autofac.Core.ImplicitRegistrationSource
                                                                                                     ---> System.ArgumentException: Requested type member cannot be found.
2024-04-29 16:33:00.727 24987-24987 DOTNET                  pid-24987                            I     at someapp.Mobile.Core.MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp()
2024-04-29 16:33:00.768 24987-24987 AndroidRuntime          pid-24987                            E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: pl.someapp.app, PID: 24987
                                                                                                    android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: [System.TypeInitializationException]: TypeInitialization_Type, Autofac.Core.ImplicitRegistrationSource
                                                                                                        at Autofac.Features.OwnedInstances.OwnedInstanceRegistrationSource..ctor(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.RegisterDefaultAdapters(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at Microsoft.Maui.Hosting.MauiAppBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1[[Autofac.ContainerBuilder, Autofac, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da]].<ConfigureContainer>b__0(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at Microsoft.Maui.Hosting.MauiAppBuilder.Build(Unknown Source:0)

From Debugging it looks like it throws inside ImplicitRegistrationSource:
private static readonly MethodInfo CreateRegistrationMethod = typeof(ImplicitRegistrationSource).GetDeclaredMethod(nameof(CreateRegistration));

But I don't get what could be an exact issue.
Any ideas?

You can try to disable the Linker behavior option and try again. For more information, please check document: Linking a .NET MAUI Android app.
